# Why Password reset unsuccessful in django rest-auth password reset

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I have problem with django rest-auth password rest.

this is my `urls.py` file(main urls)

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from rest_framework import permissions
from drf_yasg.views import get_schema_view
from drf_yasg import openapi

app_name= 'accounts'

schema_view = get_schema_view(
    openapi.Info(
        title='Blog API',
        description='oddiy API loyixasi',
        default_version='v1',
        terms_of_service='https://google.com.policies.terms',
        contact=openapi.Contact(email="xatamjonovulugbek17@gmail.com"),
        license=openapi.License('Blog API litsenziasi'),
    ),
    public=True,
    permission_classes=(permissions.AllowAny, ),
)

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('users/', include('accounts.urls')),
    path('', include('product.urls')),

    path('dj-rest-auth/registration/', include('dj_rest_auth.registration.urls')),
    path('dj-rest-auth/', include('dj_rest_auth.urls')),
    path(r'^', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    
    path('auth/', include('rest_framework.urls')),
    path('allauth/', include('allauth.urls')),
    
    path('swagger/', schema_view.with_ui('swagger', cache_timeout=0), name='schema-swagger-ui'),
    path('redoc/', schema_view.with_ui('redoc', cache_timeout=0), name='schema-radoc'),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

I added `path(r'^', include('django.contrib.auth.urls'))` to `urls.py`

This url sent mail to counsol but I enter url in mail, I take this error:
[image]

```
Password reset unsuccessful
The password reset link was invalid, possibly because it has already been used. Please request a new password reset.
```

Please give me solve

Answer (score 0):

```
path('account/api/password_reset/',PasswordResetView.as_view(), name='password_reset'),
path('account/api/password_reset_confirm/<uidb64>/<token>/', PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(), name='password_reset_confirm'),
```

In case you are still working on this issue, the following urlpattern worked for me: [urlpatterns link](https://github.com/iarsham/RestApi-Blog/blob/main/code/Config/urls.py#L32#L36).

Also, read the FAQ questions 1 and 2. It seems to be a common issue. [Source](https://dj-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32601951)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Buzz Just made the required changes.